# Is it possible to delete the bytes io.BytesIO after they've been read from memory?

Tags: python, file, stream

I want to use the BytesIO class from io to create a data stream, but if I pipe big masses of data through it, it uses much memory, so I'm asking if its possible to free the memory used by "old" data I already read.

If this isn't possible with the io module, I am open to other solutions to my problem.

Here are is the way its implemented right now:

```py
def __init__():
        self.audio: av.container.InputContainer = av.open(
            stream, "r", timeout=8, options=options, format="webm"
        )
        self.audio_stream: av.audio.stream.AudioStream = self.audio.streams.get(
            audio=0
        )[0]

        self.output_buffer: io.BytesIO = io.BytesIO(b"")
        self.output_container: av.container.OutputContainer = av.open(
            self.output_buffer, "w", format="opus"
        )

        self.output_stream: av.audio.stream.AudioStream = self.output_container.add_stream(
            "libopus", 48000
        )

...


def fill(self):
    position = 0
    for packet in self.audio.demux(self.audio_stream):
        packet: av.Packet
        position += packet.duration
        self.output_buffer.seek(0, 2)
        self.output_container.mux_one(packet)

...

# then you can read from the buffer with
b = self.output_buffer.read(bytes_to_read)
# this should be Opus Encoded Audio data in bytes format
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show how you are piping data to that object? That way we can give you an answer that best suits your use case

Comment: @C.Nivs I think the formulation is a bit weird, I just use `io_bytes_object.write(data)` for now.

Comment: but where is that data coming from? That's what will determine what the answer is

Comment: It's from an audio stream after demuxing it, coming from the PyAV library (Its an libav wrapper).

Comment: ok, can you put some code in your question to show (in a minimal way) how that data gets generated and put into the `BytesIO` object?

Comment: @C.Nivs https://docs.mikeboers.com/pyav/develop/api/_globals.html as you see in the documentation, you can put a file-like object (like io.BytesIO) as a file and the library will add the data for you. I don't think an code example is useful here.

Comment: Yes, I can read the documentation, but I haven't used that library, and this seems to be an interface function for reading and writing data. But if you are using it to *write* data to a buffer, it's still unclear where that data is coming from. Please add code to your question, code will help with misunderstandings and any perceived vague-ness. Remember, I'm not looking at your code, and there's no guarantee that people looking at this question have used this library before

Comment: @C.Nivs I hope the code provided helps.

Comment: Looks much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone still reading, I found a solution working for me.
With python's os module you can create a new pipe (`os.pipe()`), which handles all these tasks for you.

Comment: Hi could you please elaborate on how you used `os.pipe()` for this purpose please? Thanks in advance.